# What is the relationship between fame and infamy?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In layman's terms, what is the relationship between fame and infamy? Is fame required to be infamous? Are they (definitively) mutual exclusive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fame is any kind of fame.  Osama bin Laden and Steve Carell are both famous.  Only bin Laden is infamous.

Comment: +1. Quite explicitly, two of the most common words for famous in Mandarin are: yǒumíng (有名 *having* + *name*) and wénmín (闻名 literally *estimable* + *name*).  Another proof that being well known and being well regarded are two different things.

Comment: So, someone like Khalid Sheikh Mohammed - he wasn't exactly famous, so does that mean he couldn't be infamous? As in, was bin Laden infamous for his deeds of planning and orchestration, but famous for his personality and publicity?

Comment: @glowcoder Yes exactly.  You can say that bin Laden was famous for the planning and orchestration as well, though, you just can't say he was infamous for his personality.  "famous" doesn't distinguish between the reasons, whereas "infamous" is "famous for bad reasons".

Comment: And again "famous for bad reasons" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @zizi -- "famous for *doing* something bad".  You know, like killing a bunch of innocent people.  And @everybodyelse -- bin Laden's personality?  Like what?  His quirky sense of humor?  His huge collection of whoopie cushions?  If OBL chose not to kill people, he'd be about as famous as my garbageman.

Comment: @palooka: famous is an attribute, like rich.  Whether you made the money by working hard or by stealing it doesn't alter the figures in the bank.  Similarly, the fact that everybody has heard of OBL makes him famous, full stop.

Answer (score 1):

[Infamous](http://www.google.ca/search?q=define%3Ainfamous):

> Well known for some bad quality or deed.

Whereas famous is just "well known".  So everyone who has infamy has fame, but not everyone who has fame has infamy.

Comment: Is it necessary that there's no distinction between well known and famous?

Comment: How someone is "well" known for "bad" quality?

Comment: @glowcoder If you wanted to distinguish, "famous" would be "*very* well known".

Comment: @zizi "Well" describes how they are known (it's an adverb), not why they are known.

Comment: @Matthew Read But i got some positive impression when i read "Well" known ..

Comment: @zizi Think of "well" as meaning "very" or in some cases "throughly" in this context.

Comment: Then it works for me."well known for bad quality" is something like "An honest thief".